# Xcode - Attaching Third-Party Source Code for "Jump to Definition"

Tags: c++, xcode, eclipse-cdt

My C++ project depends on several open-source third party libraries. Including the headers and .dylib files lets me successfully build the project, and executing a "Jump to Definition" anywhere in my own code takes me to the function **declaration** in the proper header file.

In Eclipse CDT, I can add the library source code just for indexing, such that it is possible to do both "Jump to Declaration" (to the third-party header file) and "Jump to Definition" (to the third-party .cpp file).

Can I do that in Xcode as well? I.e. "attach" the source code of a third-party library for quick navigation, without including the library source code in the build process?

My guess is that building the third-party library from sources and adding a dependency to my project would work, but given that I already have the .dylib file and can build my project, I would strongly prefer not having to do that.

Comment: "Jump to Declaration" and "Jump to Definition" existed long before Eclipse or Visual Studio as case sensitive searches for the function name in either headers or implementation files ...

Comment: Of course. There are also many fine solutions (such as Ctags) outside of Xcode. The question is whether it can be done as conveniently and fast as `cmd-click` from inside Xcode.